# Container->get('route') method in slim framework

Tags: php, twig, slim

What does  Container->get('route') method returns and why
It is used in twig extension with slim

Answer (score 0):

The Slim Twig extension requires the `router` (not the route) instance for the custom template functions like `path_for()` and `base_url()`.

Example:

```
// Register Twig View helper
$container['view'] = function ($c) {
    $view = new \Slim\Views\Twig('path/to/templates', [
        'cache' => 'path/to/cache'
    ]);

    // Instantiate and add Slim specific extension
    $router = $c->get('router');
    $uri = \Slim\Http\Uri::createFromEnvironment(new \Slim\Http\Environment($_SERVER));
    $view->addExtension(new \Slim\Views\TwigExtension($router, $uri));

    return $view;
};
```

Please read the [slimphp/Twig-View documentation](https://github.com/slimphp/Twig-View).

Comment: What does the uri variable represents in twig extension does it represent domain or path to slim

Comment: The $uri variable represents the Scheme (e.g. http or https), Host (e.g. example.com), Port (e.g. 80 or 443), Path (e.g. /users/1) and Query string of the request URL. [See The Request URI](https://www.slimframework.com/docs/v3/objects/request.html#the-request-uri)

Comment: Why does twig extension require basepath